# How to select display:none labels from the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to select all labels inside a div that are only  apply style display:none

labels like below

```
<label for="txtAmount_146" generated="true" class="errortd" style="display: none; ">This field is required.</label>
```

i tried

```
 if($('.errortd', this).not(':hidden')){
                            alert($(this).text())
                           }
```

I have no luck still any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select all labels that have "display:none" and do something, right?

Consider this html:

```
<div id="something">
    <label class="errortd" style="display: none; ">This field is required 1.</label>
    <label class="errortd" >This field is required 2.</label>
    <label class="errortd" style="display: none; ">This field is required 3.</label>
</div>
```

You can alert the text of the first and third label with this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#something label:hidden').each(function(){
    alert( $(this).text() );
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks i have  problem i want to select the using my .errortd class
$('.errortd label:visible')

Comment: $('.errortd:visible').each(...) it's the correct. Your code will select all errortd that have inside one label and not those who are labels.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
$("label:hidden", "div")...
```

So to do something like you do in your example do:

```
$("label:hidden", "div").each(function(i) { alert($(this).text();});
```